# Phoenix json returns only ids

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a Phoenix application with generated html as well as json api responses. This is what I have done so far:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html User users name:string email:string
mix phoenix.gen.json Api.User users --no-model
```

Then I changed the alias in UserController from "alias MyApp.Api.User" to "alias Api.User". And it works! .. well mostly!

This is what I get in http response:

```
{"data":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]}
```

The problem I am trying to fix is - when I call GET on the Api, I just get a list of id's; all other useful fields are not being returned. IO.inspect tells me that controller is returning everything. So it must be the view which is filtering out fields.

However, my understanding of Elixir/Phoenix falls short here. This is what I see:

```
  def render("index.json", %{users: users}) do
    %{data: render_many(users, MyApp.Api.UserView, "user.json")}
  end
```

My basic question is - How can I dive in render_many method and find out what is happening to fix this?

My secondary questions are:

- Is there any good resource to get html and json api's working
  together in Phoenix?
- What is "user.json" in the code above? With regards to "index.json", I think it is used only for pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

There should be the following code in `web/views/api/user_view.ex`:

```
def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{id: user.id}
end
```

You just need to add more fields to that:

```
def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email}
end
```

or

```
def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
  Map.take(user, [:id, :name, :email])
end
```

The [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render_many/4) explains how `Phoenix.View.render_many/4` works in detail.

> Is there any good resource to get html and json api's working together in Phoenix?

I'm not aware of any.

> What is "user.json" in the code above? With regards to "index.json", I think it is used only for pattern matching.

Yes, that parameter is passed to `render` by `render_many`. See the documentation link above.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good resource to get html and json api's working together in Phoenix?

If your html and json use the same resource & logic, and they probably should, you can do the following:

In your view, define both ".html" and ".json" clauses, e.g.

```
def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
  %{...}
end

def render("show.html", %{user: user}) do
  render ...
end
```

In your controller, change the string, e.g. `"show.html"`, to an atom without the suffix, e.g. `:show`

In your router, make sure you accept both `html` and `json` in your pipeline

And phoenix should render the responses in the according format when requests come in.

Comment: In that case controller will have to know whether the requested resource is html or json, which could possibly be read from connection object. The other problem is - the default html and json api controllers are different. The json api controller is adding status code to response, whereas the html controller does not do that.

Comment: the status code does not really matter that much to requests that expect html. @user246615